# How do i stop v-hover from firing my function in Vuetify

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I have this v-card I'm using to display some movie data.  the v-card has a v-hover around it, and in the v-card-subtitle, I'm using a function to return some filtered data. The problem is that each time I mouse enter and mouseleave the v-card the function inside v-card-subtitle gets called.
How can I prevent it from happening?

Here is the code:

```html
<v-container>
  <v-row justify="center">
    <v-hover v-slot:default="{ hover }" :value="isHover">
      <v-card flat width="200px" height="100%" :elevation="hover ? 12 : 0">
        <v-card-title>{{ movie.title }}</v-card-title>
        <v-card-subtitle>{{ getMovieGenre(movie.genres) }}</v-card-subtitle>
      </v-card>
    </v-hover>
  </v-row>
</v-container>
```

Comment: I would recommend that you use a `computed` property instead of calling a method. Looking at your code, it seems that you are not "v-for" looping a set of data, instead, you're just managing a single data which is `movie` . Computed properties are better as they are cached, they will be cached until one of their dependencies is changed. 

`getMovieGenre() {
  return this.movie.genres.filter(...);
}`

Comment: Thank you for answering, but i do actually use v-for for looping through some movies data.
I tried using mouseenter.stop and mouseleave.stop but It's still does the same as v-hover

Comment: You can decouple the movie details from the component that has "v-for" loop so that you can replace the method with computed property. 

   `<div v-for="movie in movies" ><movie-title-with-subitile-component :data="movie" /></div>`